# Installing drivers to another windows

Tags: windows, driver, winpe

I have one drive (C:\) with Windows 2008. Is that possible to install drivers to this Windows while booting from WinPE (another OS)? I couldn't find any software to do this.
So what I'm trying to do is install drivers to one Windows while booting from another Windows on separate disks.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825070.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's not impossible, but not easy either. Installing a driver is basically a matter of copying the files and editing the registry, both of which can be done remotely.

However, the problem comes from knowing which registry entries to create, with which values. This depends on the driver, the OS, hardware and a bunch of other factors. The best approach would be to install the driver normally, and take a diff of the before/after registry, if you can. If not, you could set up another Win2008 system, do the diff there, and start from that.

If you are just updating an already installed driver, copying the newer version files will likely work.

This seems like an XY problem, though - what exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be a better approach.

Comment: You don't need to do it yourself; [DISM](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825070.aspx) provides an `/Add-Driver` option.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks! That's actually pretty useful. Should be an (accepted) answer.